# Removing duplicate lines stored in a string

Tags: c++, string

I have a string containing the following:

```
This is a line.
This is another line.
This is yet another line.
This is a line.
[...]
```

How do I remove the duplicate lines from the string?

Comment: do you have just a string containing all that text or multiple strings ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instantiate a `std::set<std::string>`. Add each line to it (the `set` will implicitly pass over duplicates).

Pull the values back out using a `std::set<std::string>::const_iterator`.

Note that the lines will come back in lexographic order. If you don't want that, and have C++11 then use `std::unordered_set<std::string>` instead (acknowledge @Ivaylo Strandjev).

Answer (score 4):

A string has no notion of a line. You will have to split the lines on your own. One possible solution is to construct a `stringstream` from the string and use `getline` on it.

You can parse the lines in a `std::set<string>` or better `std::unordered_set<string>` (if `c++11` is an option) and you will automatically have only a single instance of each line stored in the set. The drawback of this solution is that it will not keep original order of the lines. If you need to keep it, then use a helper set and push the lines in a `std::vector` as well, where you put them in the original order.

Comment: Why would `std::unordered_set` be better ?

Comment: @MatthieuM. it is asymptotically faster - insert in `std::set` has a complexity of `O(log(N))` while insert in `std::unordered_set` has an amortized complexity of `O(1)` (Actually for strings the difference would be even bigger as for set each comparison is of the order of the length of the string, while with unordered_set we only compare hashes).

Comment: *it is asymptotically faster*: with a good hash function (beware of collisions), unfortunately we know neither whether the hash function is good nor whether the size of the OP's problem is sufficient to enter this asymptotic domain. *amortized complexity*: not exactly, at least not with degenerate inputs/hash functions. *while with `unordered_set` we only compare hashes*: it depends on the implementation, Boost's caches hashes but Dirkumware's does not so they handle in-bucket comparisons differently; furthermore in case of hash collision, it resorts to equality comparison. *No silver bullet.*

Answer (score 1):

You can transform the string to vector of strings, and use this piece of code to remove duplicate ones.

```
void removeDuplicate( std::vector<std::string>& vec )
{
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    vec.erase( std::unique( vec.begin(), vec.end() ), vec.end());
}
```

Comment: Please consider making your answer self-contained. Comments tend to disappear.

Comment: You might want to cite `std::stable_sort` to preserve the original order in which those lines appeared in the original string.